# Get value from the parameter of a callback function

Tags: delphi, dll, biometrics

I am using a [biometrics SDK](http://www.veridisbiometrics.com/). And I converted the headers to delphi to consume the dll.

It looks something like this:

```
const
{VrBio_EventType}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_UNPLUG               = $001; {Fingerprint scanner unplugged from the computer.}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_PLUG                 = $002; {Fingerprint scanner plugged on the computer.}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_REMOVED              = $004; {Finger removed from the fingerprint scanner.}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_PLACED               = $008; {Finger placed on the fingerprint scanner.}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_IMAGE_FRAME          = $10;  {A fingerprint frame was captured on the fingerprint scanner.}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_IMAGE_CAPTURED       = $020; {A fingerprint image was captured on the fingerprint scanner.}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_FAKE_FINGER_DETECTED = $400; {A false finger has been detected on the sensor}
  VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_FAKE_FINGER_REMOVED  = $800; {A false finger has been removed from the sensor}

type

(* Stores the parameters of the ISO 19794-4 image format. @see VGetReaderProperties @see VrBio_ReaderProperty 
typedef struct
{
    /** @see VrBio_ISO197944CompressionMode*/
    int compressionMode;
    /** @see VrBio_ISO197944ImpressionType*/
    int impressionType;
    /** @see VrBio_ISO197944FingerPosition*/    
    int fingerPosition;

}VrBio_ISO197944Parameters;
*)

  PISO197944Parameters = ^TISO197944Parameters;
  TISO197944Parameters = record
      compressionMode: Integer; { @see VrBio_ISO197944CompressionMode}
      impressionType: Integer;  { @see VrBio_ISO197944ImpressionType}
      fingerPosition: Integer;  { @see VrBio_ISO197944FingerPosition}
  end;

(* Represents a biometric image. @see VrBio_CaptureEventCallback \ref VSyncCapture 
struct VrBio_BiometricImage
{
  /** Image width.*/
  int width;
  /**Image height*/
  int height;
  /**Image resolution in dpi. For the obsolete functions, use pixels/cm.*/
  int resolution;
  /**Number of channels in the image. Fingerprint images should always be grayscale, so this value is always 1.*/
  int channels;
  /**Biometric modality. 
  * Always use VRBIO_BIOMETRIC_MODALITY_FINGERPRINT. 
  * \ref VrBio_BiometricModality.
  */
  int biometricModality;
  /**Scanner type. 
  * \ref VrBio_ScannerType.
  */
  int scannerType;
  /**Formato de imagem: Formato da imagem.
  *\ ref VrBio_ImageFormat.*/
  int imageFormat;
  /**Size of the buffer*/
  int bufferSize;
  /**Compression rate. Valid for images that allow compression.
  * \ref VrBio_CompressionRate
  */
  int compressionRate; 
 /**Quality of the fingerprint image. 
  * \ref VrBio_FingerQuality
  */
  int fingerQuality;

  /** Only valid if the image if imageFormat is \ref VrBio_ImageFormat::VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_ISO19794_4 
  *\ref VrBio_ISO197944Parameters
  */
  VrBio_ISO197944Parameters* ISO197944_parameters;

  /** Buffer storing the pixels of the image.
    The position(x,y,c) of a pixel is y*width*channels+x*channels+c.
  */
  unsigned char* buffer;

  /**Reserved for future use*/
  void* reserved;
};

typedef struct VrBio_BiometricImage VrBio_BiometricImage;
*)
  PBiometricImage = ^TBiometricImage;
  TBiometricImage = record
    width: Integer;                             { Image width. }
    height: Integer;                            { Image height }
    resolution: Integer;                        { Image resolution in dpi. For the obsolete functions, use pixels/cm.}
    channels: Integer;                          { Number of channels in the image. Fingerprint images should always be grayscale, so this value is always 1. }
    biometricModality: Integer;                 { Biometric modality. Always use VRBIO_BIOMETRIC_MODALITY_FINGERPRINT. \ref VrBio_BiometricModality. }
    scannerType: Integer;                       { Scanner type. \ref VrBio_ScannerType. }
    imageFormat: Integer;                       { Formato de imagem: Formato da imagem. \ ref VrBio_ImageFormat. }
    bufferSize: Integer;                        { Size of the buffer }
    compressionRate: Integer;                   { Compression rate. Valid for images that allow compression. \ref VrBio_CompressionRate }
    fingerQuality: Integer;                     { Quality of the fingerprint image. \ref VrBio_FingerQuality }
    ISO197944_parameters: PISO197944Parameters; { Only valid if the image if imageFormat is \ref VrBio_ImageFormat::VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_ISO19794_4 \ref VrBio_ISO197944Parameters }
    buffer: PByte;                              { Buffer storing the pixels of the image. The position(x,y,c) of a pixel is y*width*channels+x*channels+c. }
    reserved: Pointer;                          { Reserved for future use }
  end;

(*
#include "VTypes.h"

#ifdef WIN32
#define DLLIMPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall
#else
#define DLLIMPORT extern "C"
#endif
*)

{ Callback function that receives events..
typedef void (*VrBio_CaptureEventCallback) (
                   int  eventType, 
            const char* readerName, 
  VrBio_BiometricImage* image, 
            const void* userData)
}
  TCaptureEventCallback = procedure(eventType: Integer; readerName: PAnsiChar; image: PBiometricImage; userData: Pointer); stdcall;

{ Function responsible for initializing the SDK. This function MUST be called before calling any other method, except \ref VInstallLicense
  DLLIMPORT  VStartSDK(VrBio_CaptureEventCallback eventCallback);
}
  function VStartSDK(eventCallback: TCaptureEventCallback): Integer; stdcall;

{ Function responsible for finalizing the SDK. This function should be called when the SDK is not needed in the application anymore.
  DLLIMPORT  VStopSDK();
}
  function VStopSDK(): Integer; stdcall;

{ Function responsible for starting the capture on a specific fingerprint reader.
  After calling this function, the application is able to receive events.
  DLLIMPORT  VStartReader(const char* readerName);
}
  function VStartReader(readerName: PAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;
```

Using it looks like this:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure EventCallback(eventType: Integer; readerName: PAnsiChar; image: PBiometricImage; userData: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  case eventType of
    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_UNPLUG:               Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Leitor desconectado!');
    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_REMOVED:              Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Dedo removido!');
    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_PLACED:               Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Dedo detectado!');
    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_IMAGE_FRAME:          Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Frame capturado!');
    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_IMAGE_CAPTURED:       Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Imagem capturada!');
    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_FAKE_FINGER_DETECTED: Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Dedo falso detectado!');
    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_FAKE_FINGER_REMOVED:  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Dedo falso removido!');

    VRBIO_CAPTURE_EVENT_PLUG:
    begin
      VStartReader(readerName);
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Leitor conectado!');
    end;

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VStartSDK(EventCallback);
end;
```

My questions:

I can use the application and get the `Plug`, `Unplug` and `Placed` events, but when I get the `Image Captured` event I have an acces vilation.
In the events that are working the `EventCallback` parameter image is `nil`. Is the TBiometricImage record conversion correct?

How can I convert the TBiometricImage buffer to a TBitmap and display the captured image in a TImage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I get the Image Captured event I have an acces vilation. In the events that are working the EventCallback parameter image is nil. Is the TBiometricImage record conversion correct?

The individual fields are declared fine, but double check that the alignment and padding of your Delphi records match the same alignment and padding used by the structs in C/C++.

Also, more importantly, the `VrBio_CaptureEventCallback` typedef in C/C++ is declared without any calling convention specified, so it will use the compiler's default convention, which is usually `__cdecl` instead of `__stdcall` (can be configured in the compiler settings). In Delphi, you declared `TCaptureEventCallback` to use `stdcall` instead of `cdecl`.  You have to make sure you match the calling conventions correctly (the exported DLL functions do use `stdcall`, so you are OK there).

> How can I convert the TBiometricImage buffer to a TBitmap and display the captured image in a TImage?

The SDK documentation does not explain how to process the various image formats.  However, just looking at the struct declaration, the `buffer` field points at the actual image data, and the `imageFormat` field indicates the format of that data (there is a `VrBio_ImageFormat` enum that you have not translated yet).  So, you would have to look at the `imageFormat` first to know how to interpret the `buffer`.

I do see a `VConvertImage()` function available.  So you should be able to convert images to BMP format, if they are not already.  Based on the samples in the SDK, it looks like the `buffer` data *might* be a standard BMP file format, so you could try copying the `buffer` to a `TMemoryStream` and then use the `TBitmap.LoadFromStream()` method.

There are also GIF and JPG image formats available, which could be handled by `TGIFImage` and `TJPEGImage`, respectively, or even `TWICImage`, if you wanted  to display scanned GIF/JPG images without having to convert them to BMP first.  There is also a RAW image format available (which apparently your images are using), but there is no standard VCL `TGraphic` class to handle RAW images, but I think there might be some 3rd party classes floating around if you look around.

Otherwise, you might try converting the image data to BMP, if needed, and then pass the `buffer` to the Win32 API `CreateBitmap/Indirect()` or `CreateDibSection()` function, and then assign the resulting `HBITMAP` to the `TBitmap.Handle` property if successful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right about the calling convention, I can capture all the events now!
In fact there are other structures that I did not put into the question. `VrBio_ImageFormat` looks like this:  
   `TImageFormat = (  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_UNKNOWN,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_RAW,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_BMP,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_WSQ,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_ISO19794_4,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_JPEG,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_TIFF,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_PNG,  
     VRBIO_IMAGEFORMAT_GIF);`  
The format I get is `RAW`.

Comment: Again, without seeing the SDK documentation, there is no way for anyone here to know what the pixel data looks like for any given image type. Maybe `RAW` data is RGB colors, or maybe the data is an actual [RAW image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) instead.

Comment: Thanks for everything, I can display the image using `VConvertImage()`.